# Test React Reducer using Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.  I have a reducer like this in my react app.

reducer.ts

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import FormField from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormField'
import FormFieldLabel from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormFieldLabel'
import FormFieldErrors from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormFieldErrors'
import Translatable from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/Translatable'
import Block from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/Block'
import withStrings from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/withStrings'

import { getMemoLabel } from '../../../../lib/utils/manage-payee-util'
import FormInput from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormInput'
import withMemoValidation from './withMemoValidation'
import ArialiveMemo from './ArialiveMemo'
import styles from './Memo.less'
import FormFieldErrorIcon from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormFieldErrorIcon'
import { MEMO_MAX_CHARS } from '../../../../components/workflows/edit-payment/constants'

const Memo = ({
  fieldId,
  defaultMemo,
  memo,
  isConfirm,
  getString,
  validateMemoField,
  userTypedMemo,
  isMemoFieldError,
  memoFieldValidate,
  defaultMemoValidate
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    memoFieldValidate(userTypedMemo <= MEMO_MAX_CHARS)
  }, [userTypedMemo, memoFieldValidate] )

  useEffect(() => {
    defaultMemoValidate(defaultMemo && defaultMemo.length <= MEMO_MAX_CHARS)
  }, [defaultMemo, defaultMemoValidate] )


  const memoLabel = getMemoLabel()
  return !isConfirm ? (
    <Block className={styles.memo}>
      <FormField fieldId={fieldId}>
        <FormFieldLabel>
          { isMemoFieldError &&
          <FormFieldErrorIcon className={styles.errorIcon} />
          }
          <div className={isMemoFieldError ? styles.errorMemoLabel : styles.memoLabel}>
            <Translatable id={memoLabel} />
          </div>
        </FormFieldLabel>
        <FormInput
          className={isMemoFieldError ? styles.inputerror : styles.input}
          initialValue={defaultMemo}
          onChange={validateMemoField}
          type="text"
          maxLength={MEMO_MAX_CHARS}
          placeholder={getString('memoPlaceholder')}
          deleteOnUnmount={true}
        />
        <FormFieldErrors />
        {userTypedMemo && <ArialiveMemo count={userTypedMemo} />}
      </FormField>
    </Block>
  ) : (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Translatable id={memoLabel} />
      <Block>
        <strong className={memo.length > MEMO_MAX_CHARS ? styles.inputerror : ''}>
          {memo}
        </strong>
      </Block>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Memo.defaultProps = {
  isConfirm: false
}

Memo.propTypes = {
  fieldId: PropTypes.string,
  defaultMemo: PropTypes.string,
  isConfirm: PropTypes.bool,
  memo: PropTypes.string,
  validateMemoField: PropTypes.func,
  userTypedMemo: PropTypes.number,
  isMemoFieldError: PropTypes.bool,
  memoFieldValidate: PropTypes.func,
  defaultMemoValidate: PropTypes.func
}

export default withMemoValidation(withStrings(Memo))
```

However, when i run `test-cov`, it says that Line 2, 3 and 8 are not covered. How do i cover the if else condition in the reducer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test case isn't testing correctly, `clearErrors` takes in two arguments: `state` and `action` but you pass in only `CARD_TYPES.REWARD` into the `clearErrors` function.

So you just have to provide the correct unit tests to cover for each of those conditions :)

Line 2: `if (action.payload.cardType === CARD_TYPES.REWARD) {`

Line 3: `return {`

```
  it("should clear out error codes", () => {
    const action = { payload: { cardType: CARD_TYPES.REWARD } };
    const state = clearErrors(initialState, action);
    const expectedState = { ... };
    expect(state).toEqual(expectedState);
  });
```

Line 8: `return state;`

```
  it("should not clear out error codes", () => {
    const action = { payload: { cardType: 'other' } };
    const state = clearErrors(initialState, action);
    expect(state).toEqual(initialState);
  });
```

Comment: @user3019647 no worries!